# Check if Email Address Belongs to Yahoo?

Tags: asp.net, email, yahoo

```
private byte[] BytesFromString(string str)
    {
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
    }
    private int GetResponseCode(string ResponseString)
    {
        return int.Parse(ResponseString.Substring(0, 3));
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TcpClient tClient = new TcpClient("plus.smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 465);
        string CRLF = "\r\n";
        byte[] dataBuffer;
        string ResponseString;
        NetworkStream netStream = tClient.GetStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(netStream);
        ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();
        dataBuffer = BytesFromString("HELO " + CRLF);
        netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
        ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();
        dataBuffer = BytesFromString("MAIL FROM:<myemail@yahoo.com>" + CRLF);
        netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
        ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();
        dataBuffer = BytesFromString("RCPT TO:<" + TextBox1.Text.Trim() + ">" + CRLF);
        netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
        ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();
        if (GetResponseCode(ResponseString) == 550)
        {
            Response.Write("Mai Address Does not Exist !");
        }
        dataBuffer = BytesFromString("QUITE" + CRLF);
        netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
        tClient.Close();
    }
```

Hi, this code does not work with smtp yahoo server but code work with gmail smtp server  `TcpClient tClient = new TcpClient("gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com", 25)`

> error:An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine in line Response String = reader.ReadLine();

and change port server to 25 not happen!
    Whether  smtp server and port server is valid?
    Is there a way to make sure of is email valid?
    someone could help me?

Comment: please see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040104/verify-that-email-domain-exists

Answer (score 0):

Some Server machine used to algorithm for responsing to fetch data from it's particular server than that machine can't responding.....

but as you say gmail provide data therefore that machine can't use any restriction for responding data......